# modify tweet call for origin being the application

Tags: perl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've currently built the twitter handling for posting a tweet. Unknowingly, i built for the tweet to come from the authroized user, and we actually want to tweet from our app itself. How do I tweak this code to post `on behalf of the application itself`.

```
use Net::Twitter;
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits   => [qw/OAuth API::RESTv1_1/],
    consumer_key => '',
    consumer_secret => '',
    access_token => '',
    access_token_secret => '',
);
my $result = $nt->update('Hello, world!');
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Only authenticated users can post tweets.

Comment: @MattJacob But how do I make a post on behalf of my application?

Comment: Do you have a separate Twitter account for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to regenerate the authorisation tokens while you're logged into Twitter as the account that you want to tweet from.